# Post to a servlet from AJAX code Syntax issues

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, path

I am sending some data from AJAX to a servlet. This syntax works very well on my local.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../MyTestServlet?section="+sId, true);
```

However, on our DEV UNIX server this does not work. I tried the following, but this does not work

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyTestServlet?section=+sId", true);
```

The servlets are in the following package "`com.myPackage.myApp.servlets`"

What would be the right syntax?

Comment: Did you map your servlet in your web app's web.xml file ?

Comment: Please elaborate "does not work". This is unhelpful information. Describe the concrete problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective.

Comment: @rickzIts mapped. AsI mentioned in my post, this works on my local, but not on the server.

Comment: @BalusC : The AJAX code just does not hit the servlet.In the servlet, I log some info to console if the AJAX hits the servlet. That log is visble in the first case and not in the second even on my local

Comment: @Raghu: You can examine request using Mozilla Firefox `Net` plugin. If it does not hit the servlet.Check your servlet mappings

Comment: 1 error I already see, is `+sId` is in the url string. Secondy, I recommend you to get sure that `<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyTestServlet?section=` equals `../MyTestServlet?section=` - console.log those paths to check. And lastly, as Mishra said, look at the `Net` option in firebug or Network in chrome to see info about client-server communication

Answer (score 0):

Try using real path on the server system

[ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was not so much the path of the servlet, but a different one. Actually the Query.properties file also had path issues and once I solved it, it started to work. So actually the first link worked. Sorry folks for wasting your time on this one.  Thanks for all the responses.